# Creating Flow Chart with Bezier Curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

How would I use TikZ to make this diagram? I would like to use bezier curves instead of straight lines, too.

[image]

thanks

Comment: A couple of question. First, how exactly do you want the curves? (A rough illustration would be helpful; the diagram above looks hand-drawn, so it's somewhat surprising if lines were used when curves were preferred.) Secondly, do you want the font size to change as in the diagram, or do you want it consistent (with lots of whitespace)?

Comment: Please provide an MWE demonstrating what you have tried yourself next time. It is not really reasonable to expect others to do all the work. However, since percusse has already provided an answer, I guess it is a little late to ask for one at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiled with `lualatex`:

```tex
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{pgf}

\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\usegdlibrary{circular}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners]
    \graph [simple necklace layout,
    edge quotes mid,
    edges={nodes={font=\scriptsize, fill=white, sloped, inner sep=1pt}}]
     {
         Father[nail at={(0,3)}] <->["is", blue, text=black] God[nail at={(0,0)}];
         Son[nail at={(-3,-2)}] <->["is", blue, text=black] God;
         Holy Ghost[nail at={(3,-2)}] <->["is", blue, text=black] God;
         Father <->["is not", red, text=black] Son <->["is not", red, text=black] Holy Ghost <->["is not", red, text=black] Father;
         Father -> ["paternity", bend right=22.5, green, text=black] Son;
         Son -> ["filiation", bend left=45, green, text=black] Father;
         Father -> ["active spiration", bend left=22.5, green, text=black] Holy Ghost;
         Holy Ghost -> ["passive spiration", bend right=45, green, text=black] Father;
         Holy Ghost -> ["passive spiration", bend left=45, green, text=black] Son;
         Holy Ghost <- ["active spiration", bend left=22.5, green, text=black] Son;
      };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Holy Trinity relations]

Answer (score 8):

My Christianity knowledge is negligible so I don't know much of this edge problem. I'll use my limited popular culture knowledge instead, there you go; I'll click that button and expect a few lightning strikes (one would be enough though considering God being also an aimbot if he wished to).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\usepackage{god3} % Hoped to have a LaTeX3 solution, didn't work
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,circle,draw,minimum size=2cm}]
\node (f) at (3,5) {Marlon\\Brando};
\node (s) at (0,0) {Al\\Pacino};
\node (p) at (6,0) {Vodka};
\node (g) at ($(s)!0.5!(p)!0.3333!(f)$) {Morgan\\Freeman};

\foreach \x[remember=\x as \xi (initially f),count=\xc from 1] in {s,p,f}{
\draw (g) -- (\x) node[midway,draw=none,minimum size=1mm,fill=white] {IS};
\draw (\x) to[out={\xc*135},in={(\xc*120}] node[midway,draw=none,minimum size=1mm,fill=white] {IS\\NOT}(\xi);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Lack of MWE led me to this blasphemy.

Comment: I heard there would be free vodka in here. `:)`

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\def\Box#1{\parbox[b]{15mm}{\centering #1}}

\begin{document}
\large
\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=10mm,rowsep=17.3mm,mnode=Circle,radius=12mm,arrowscale=2]
    & [name=b] \Box{The\\Boss} \\
    &  [name=g] \Box{Ghost}\\   
    [name=t] \Box{The\\TikZ} & & [name=h] \Box{The\\Holy\\PSTricks}
    \ncarc[arcangle=45]{<-}{t}{b}\naput[nrot=:U]{does not like}
    \ncarc[arcangle=45]{->}{b}{h}\naput[nrot=:U]{likes}
    \ncarc[arcangle=-45]{t}{h}
    \ncline{<-}{t}{g}\naput[nrot=:U]{likes}
\end{psmatrix}
\end{document}
```

[image]